# Learning Python - Equality operators not working inside while loop

Tags: python

I beging to lean python recently and I am stuck with this problem that I don't understand why its not working as expected...

```
a = 2
b = 2

c = 6
x = 2

ab_cx = a == b and c == x

while x < 8:
    x += 1
    if ab_cx:
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```

In my mind once x becomes 6 it should print Eureka! but thats isn't what I am getting...

But if I just write this... then the == works as I suppose they should... what is the difference.??

```
a = 2
b = 2

c = 6
x = 6

ab_cx = a == b and c == x


if ab_cx:
    print('Eureka')
else:
    print('Not there yet..!')
```

Thank you all for your time...

Comment: Value of `ab_cx` is computed only once, outside of the loop.

Comment: You set the value of ``ab_cx`` ONCE, before the loop.  It isn't going to magically update its value just because you changed one of the variables that was used in calculating its original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Jay suggested write the conditional in the while-loop:

```
a = 2
b = 2

c = 6
x = 2

while x < 8:
    x += 1
    if (a == b and c == x):
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```

You cannot save the conditional in "ab_cx". "ab_cx" is already evaluated

Better than a while loop is a for loop:

```
a = 2
b = 2

c = 6
x = 2

for x in range(2, 8 + 1):
    if (a == b and c == x):
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```

A for-loop is usually faster than a while loop and it is more difficult to build an endless loop than it is by using a while loop.

Please notice the (8+1), that is no mistake this is necessary!

James.

Comment: JMat was a little bit faster, using a function would solve the problem too

Comment: Appreciated your help... but just out of curiosity why 8 + 1 and not just 9 since its the same..?

Comment: I used 8 + 1 to make clear, that there is a need to add plus one to your original limit. I also thought about the use of a dynamic limit, where you have to use the +1.

Answer (score 1):

write `ab_cx = a == b and c == x` line into while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You never update ab_cx which is what evaluates to true/false in the conditional, you only update x, after the point of having evaluated ab_cx

Answer (score 1):

Your "ab_cx" is not a method but a value.

You can either make a method of it, or repeat the ab_cx = a == b and c == x in your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
ab_cx = a == b and c == x
```

Does not store a statement in `ab_cx`. Instead, it will evaluate `a==b and c==x` and store the result in `ab_cx`.
Which in your case is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
ab_cx = a == b and c == x
```

Is computed only once before entering the loop and it takes the value `False`. So, even though you have changed the `x` later, the value of `ab_cx` does not change. You can write the line inside of the loop to obtain the result you expect.

```
a = 2
b = 2

c = 6
x = 2

while x < 8:
    x += 1
    ab_cx = a == b and c == x
    if ab_cx:
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```

Answer (score 0):

you define the variable `ab_cx` before the loop, and at this moment it takes the value `False` and is of type `bool`.

This is a static assignation, this value won't change until you ask python to change it.

therefore your variable is always equal to `False`

If you want your program to work, you can either change the value at each iteration:

```
a = 2

b = 2

c = 6
x = 2



while x < 8:
    x += 1
    ab_cx = a == b and c == x
    if ab_cx:
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```

or define it as a function:

```
a = 2

b = 2

c = 6
x = 2
def ab_cx(a,b,c,x): return a == b and c == x

while x < 8:
    x += 1

    if ab_cx(a,b,c,x):
        print('Eureka')
    else:
        print(x, ' - No... Not there yet..!')
```